Motor and Controller to spin Camera Array
I am in over my depth with respect to motors and drive hardware.
Problem
The motion control solutions I have tried have failed due to torque insufficiency and noise.
Seeking
I am seeking motion control motor/drive suggestions from community members who have designed motion control systems in the speed/torque/noise/cost domain described below.
Project:
Environmental device that must spin a 1 lb rotor (a cube - 12" x 12" x 12"). Attached to its four outside vertical surfaces are sensors (cameras basically).
Physics and Design Requirements:

Rotor Dimensions = Roughly 1 cu/ft (.03 m3) significant windage.
Rotor Mass = 1 lb (.45 kg) annular concentration @ 5" radius
Slew Speed = 45 RPM
Operational Speed = 350 RPM
Torque to maintain 340 RPM = 60 Ncm (4.5 lb/in) (measured with load cell)
Max time to ramp/accelerate from 45 to 350 RPM = 1.5 s
Ability to home/brake on a hall sensor/magnet
MUST be nearly inaudible
Aiming for sub- $15 USD in 1k quantities.

FIRST TRY: NEMA-17 Stepper with Trinamic TMC2209 Driver.

Was very quiet at low speeds

Very low cost (step-sticks)

Features stall protection, and UART load reporting

Controllable via UART from MCU

Able to brake on hall sensor,


BUT:

Insufficient torque (I achieved only 240 RPM, with 15 second ramp)

Note: the motor was coupled to the rotor via belt/pulley. I used various ratios to align the torque curve with the load.
SECOND TRY: Brushed 30 W 12 VDC motor with TI DRV8871 driver with a 22 µF 60 V bulk cap

Very noisy - caused by the ~490 Hz PWM carrier frequency

I adjusted ATMEGA328 TCCR (WGMnn) to speed up the PWM Which eliminated the noise, but the torque is gone (can stop shaft with fingers).



The ultimate solution will likely be a large, low kv brusheless motor. Probably with a belt drive gear reduction.
Driving it as a servo will be difficult. Look at the VESC project. There is also a project called the ODrive which is exactly what you're looking for, but I personally found it to be extremely finicky and difficult to get working. Others like Stuff Made Here on youtube seem to have had the same problems with it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thanks Drew, I will follow up on your VESC and Odrive suggestions.
